# How do I change/paint the color of a closet door floor guide

Tags: floor, hardware, closet

I can only buy this from the store. I have made two pairs of Shoji doors, the frame is black, the screen is made of rice paper. I need the guides shown below to be black. Any idea what I need to do to have that color? I think that using paint for this might not work on long term.

[image]

Comment: You will have better luck looking for a metal or iron worker in your area that will fabricate something similar

Comment: Some plastics are actually porous enough that they can be heated in a dye and absorb it. It's not good for the structural integrity, but as this is just a guide, might be worth a shot. $4 for the part, $2-3 for the dye, I'd go for it.

Comment: I could try to make it of wood with my table saw ...but it requires some work

Answer (score 1):

You are probably right, spray painting is not a long term option. But if you can't find this piece manufactured in black, spray painting might be your *only* option. That being said, I would make sure you prime it first (just google spray paint primer) followed by a couple thin coats of black paint. Over time the inside "tracks" will probably wear down, but you shouldn't see much of the inside once the doors are installed. The outside facing bracket should hold up fairly well, though. Sorry I'm not coming up with a better solution, but sometimes it just helps to talk through your project. Good luck!

Comment: thanks! If there is no better option to paint it I will probably bite the bullet and try to make it out of wood. It will probably take a couple of passes through a table say and a cross cut sled which I currently don't have. Unfortunatelly a dado blade does not work on my Dewalt 7480 :-( I wish I knew that this model does not take this type of blade